# Should you design created_by and last_update_by in User table?

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Sometime back while designing something that included user management, I was required to have `created_by` and `last_updated_by` columns in the `User` table. To me it seemed a good idea to have a 1:1 relationship on `User` itself as it would serve as an additional check.

The obvious issue is creating the first user who will have to *create himself* but after that it should work fine(?) I believe. But I was asked to remove the constraint stating some reasons. What would be a good design decision?

Comment: I guess the first question is *What's the scenario?*  Why did you need to know who a user was created by and who last updated him/her?

Comment: I was told I should because it was for logging and was standard practice somehow.

Comment: Whoever told you that needs to back up his statement some more.  I can't imagine having this information without some kind of `date_last_updated` field is useful...

Comment: Oh, it did have `last_updated_on` and `created_on` columns too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer won't we very tech related: We also using different CMS for our customers and they have a "created_at" and "updated_at" column in almost all of theis tables that relate to users, products, posts, ... One week ago, I was asked to get some stats from the application. I should get how many users were active and when, when did a user log-in and did he returned in period X. From users that are not older than 1 month (speaking application wise of course) how many have actively done something on the site and so on.

There are specialized tools for something like that, of course but the data was more than enough to provide pretty detailed information on various aspects that were very important from a financial point of view as well as planning and re-thinking some aspects.

As mentioned, this is not really a datebase-design answer but I'm sure everyone who does the econimical part will be interrested in some of this data at one point. So keeping it doesn't hurt anybody but can give you cheap (because it's "already there") information for a next meeting with the customers manager or whoever.

Comment: But do you, or do you not put the foreign key constraint?

Comment: When your DBMS supports it, you should use them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server the first user could be created like this. It has worked well for me but you might have to tweak it a bit.

```
DECLARE @currentId int
SET @currentId = ident_current('[dbo].[User]') + 1;  
INSERT INTO [dbo].[User] (ExternalId, [CreatedById], [UpdatedById]) VALUES ('system',  @currentId, @currentId)
```

Example:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN (SELECT
        COUNT(1)
      FROM tablename) = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE IDENT_CURRENT('tablename') + 1
  END AS Current_Identity;
```

Source:

[How to get the next identity value from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20805067/3850405)