# Is it possible to use identity value during insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Let's say I have the following table:

```
ID Name Custom_Field
1  Alex   1_custom
2  Bob    2_somethingelse
.......
```

Can I do the insert in one sql statement? I couldn't find any function that will allow me to use my ID at the time of insert.
`ID` is `INT IDENTITY(1,1)`
I'm looking for something like this:

```
insert into table
values('Alex', ID_VALUE + '_custom')
```

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805067/how-to-get-the-next-identity-value-from-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

You could create a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table), if you always require the field values like `ID_custom`:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(
    [id] int identity, 
    [name] varchar(20),
    CustomField AS CAST(id AS varchar(10)) + '_custom'
);
```

Though you can't insert values into it (and you don't have to). So your insert statements look like this:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable
    ([name])
VALUES
    ('Alex'),
    ('Bob')
;
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/10cac/1

Comment: How the above resolved the issue ?? Btw. you should mark the computed col. as persisted.

Comment: @YogeshSharma The question does not present an issue, and I am merely pointing out a way to implement the requirement. Btw, yes the column can be marked as PERSISTED, but I don't think it is ALWAYS required. It depends on the use case.

Comment: The best approach is computed column, I aggree to @Nisarg. Persisted or not. Since Identity column cannot be updated, the value in computed column will always be parallel to identity.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last identity and increase by 1. Something like this

```
insert into table
 values('Alex', cast((select max(ID_VALUE )+1 from table) as nvarchar(10)) + '_custom')
```

There is `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function in sql server, but you can use it only after insert statement.

Comment: This could run into problems when your sql server [loses the 1000 number cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database) of identity values.